# Python nested loop for nearest neighbor classifier

Tags: python, nested-loops, nearest-neighbor

I have a list of tuples like this which is classed as unknown:

```py
unknown = [(0.678713, 0.951598),
           (-1.169512, -0.957855),
           (0.631947, 1.236489),
           (-0.131799, -0.324218),
           (-0.199565, -0.229171),
           (0.900907, 0.448131),
           (0.699395, 0.414314),
           (-1.132646, -1.013298)]
```

I have two others lists classed as red and blue:

```py
red = [(4.495835, 5.347824),
       (4.847142, 3.975707),
       (3.899234, 4.040381),
       (4.679696, 4.379142),
       (4.036405, 4.594875),
       (4.018261, 4.013737),
       (5.234569, 3.760527),
       (4.984905, 4.239113),
       (7.209045, 2.419611),
       (4.090784, 5.082992)]


blue = [(-1.136909, -0.71508),
        (-0.019995, -0.10857),
        (-0.305477, -0.83567),
        (-0.364433, -0.335014),
        (-0.687055, -0.871415),
        (-0.255737, -0.739738),
        (0.238247, 0.235795),
        (1.906042, 1.712006)]
```

I need to take 1 data point from unknown, 1 from red and blue each , calculate the minimum distance of Unknown from red and blue and classify/identify it as RED or BLUE . This process keeps going until all the data points ( 20 in total) in UNKNOWN dataset ( list of tuple ) is done and give an output about all the data points in UNKNOWN.

I can calculate the point distance from RED and BLUE and compare them from a pre selected unknown point but unable to calculate from Unknown list with red & blue list.

My understanding is that, I need to use a for loop or nested loop.
But my knowledge in coding is limited and unable to find how I code or I use any loop in terms of code. Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

```py
for unknown in unknown_dataset:
    print(unknown)
    
    min_distance_from_red = 1000
    min_distance_from_blue = 1000

    for red in red_dataset:
        distance_from_red = util.calculate_distance(unknown, red)
        min_distance_from_red = distance_from_red
    if distance_from_red < min_distance_from_red:
        min_distance_from_red 
    
    for blue in blue_dataset:
        distance_from_blue = util.calculate_distance(unknown, blue)
        min_distance_from_blue = distance_from_blue
    if distance_from_blue < min_distance_from_blue:         
        min_distance_from_blue

# compare 

if (min_distance_from_red > min_distance_from_blue):
    print (f'the coordinate {unknown} is blue')
else:      
    print(f'the coordinate {unknown} is red')
```

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: You're not updating `min_distance_from_red` or the blue version properly. Your indentation is also incorrect. You should be doing those `if` statements inside the `for` loops, and only updating the minimum distance if the current calculated distance is less than the current minimum.

Comment: if i select 1 data point from ( for example (4.918007, 4.142507) from Unknown then I get its red , if change the data points and and also get the output if its red or blue.  my code works in that case.
but I need to make a loop for the all the unknown_points rather then selecting randomly and I dont know how I can do it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. For each point in `unknown` you need to calculate its distance from EVERY point in `red` AND every point in `blue`.

Comment: using a loop which will get one unknown data point from Unknown dataset and compare with each data point in Red & Blue dataset and give an output if its red or blue (  calculating the distance from unknown and getting the minimum distance)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you like to do, assuming you want to declare the unknown tuples to the same as the nearest possible red or blue tuple:

```
def distance(u, r):
    return ((r[0]-u[0])**2+(r[1]-u[1])**2)**0.5

for u in unknown:   
    min_distance_from_red = float("inf")
    min_distance_from_blue = float("inf")
    
    for b in blue:
        distance_from_blue = distance(u, b)
        if distance_from_blue < min_distance_from_blue:         
            min_distance_from_blue = distance_from_blue
    
    for r in red:
        distance_from_red = distance(u, r)
        if distance_from_red < min_distance_from_red:
            min_distance_from_red = distance_from_red
    
    # compare
    if min_distance_from_red > min_distance_from_blue:
        print("the coordinate", u, "is blue")
    else:      
        print("the coordinate", u, "is red")
```

I added a distance function as well on top. As some commented, your indents and declarations of for loops was a bit wrong but you had the overall idea right at least. In your case, assuming your lists are declared on top, all of them turned out to be blue when I ran this code:

```
>the coordinate (0.678713, 0.951598) is blue
>the coordinate (-1.169512, -0.957855) is blue
>the coordinate (0.631947, 1.236489) is blue
>the coordinate (-0.131799, -0.324218) is blue
>the coordinate (-0.199565, -0.229171) is blue
>the coordinate (0.900907, 0.448131) is blue
>the coordinate (0.699395, 0.414314) is blue
>the coordinate (-1.132646, -1.013298) is blue
```